# Why Python script on Mac exports different tab characters?

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, python-2.7

I've a Python script which exports a list with tab delimiter (\t) and I'm using same Python script on Mac, Windows and Linux but on Mac it creates an export file with "^M^I" chars instead of just "^I" (this M-notation can be seen on `cat -te file.txt`) and it adds newline before tab.

What can be wrong with my code here?

I write lines to file with this snippet

```py
with open(linksFile, "w") as file:
    for link in link_list:
        file.write(link['from'] + '\t' + link['url'] + '\n')
```

Comment: For starters, what you have won't even run. `from` is a keyword, and ignoring that, neither `from` nor `to` are defined. Post an example that actually *works*.

Comment: Are you sure the `^M` is being added before the tab, and not the  newline? `\n` is treated in a platform-specific fashion by default; use the `newline` argument to `open` to control how `\n` is written.

Comment: @chepner yes, it's added before the tab. (as I know it's ^I with cat -te command) \n works correct.

Comment: How is `link_list` defined? Are you sure `link['from']` doesn't simply end with a carriage return already?

Comment: Also, "newline" isn't really a character; it's a virtual character whose concrete representation is a linefeed in Unix, a carriage-return/linefeed pair in Windows (and a carriage return alone on classic Mac OS, though that's just of historical interest rather than of practical significance).

Comment: @chepner no, link['from'] doesnt include any new line or tab. as I mentioned it runs very well on Windows and Linux too. In fact it might not be newline before the tab, but as I know ^M is newline on M notation.

Comment: You haven't answered my question. What's the output of `repr(link['from'])` in each case? My contention is that it's not `\t` or `write` that is being treated differently in each case, but how `link` is populated that produces the carriage return. (Specifically, do you see the carriage return appear if you put a character other than `\t` in the call to `write`?)

Comment: @chepner you were correct about link['from'], I forgot I've changed some code on part populating this and it seems it was adding carriage return. Thank you very much.